# In Libgdx running on Android, load show() concurrently or parallel to render()

Tags: android, multithreading, libgdx

I have a time-sensitive application.  Several screens load during the course of the program calling show() which is very similar to Screen.show().

But, show() has to be called while render() is also being called.  I can deal with the additional problems of managing parallel drawbacks (race conditions and dead locks).  But I don't know if it is possible to tell Android to spawn two GLThreads ?

From documentation, and from chasing around a bug, I learned libgdx components must be initialized, rendered, and disposed of in the GLThread.

How can I load the LibGdx components (Sprite, Texture, BitmapFonts etc) in a background thread ?

Comment: As I know, it is impossible to host 2 OpenGL threads. But you can look deeper inside async loaders for assets manager to get a point of how to load them in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libgdx on Android only supports one GLThread, so all OpenGL operations must take place on that thread.  There are two basic techniques to avoid blocking your GLThread from invoking render.

First, make sure to do all the non-GL operations on background threads (e.g., loading bytes from disk, converting them to the correct format, etc).  This is generally what the Libgdx [Asset Manager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) is designed to support.

Second, instead of doing all the required OpenGL work in a single step, break your load or into finer pieces, and only do one (or fewer pieces) at a time.  For example, just load a single Sprite from its texture data into the OpenGL state during one render loop.  I believe if you use the AssetManager `isLoaded` in preference to `update` you may get this semantic (but I'm not entirely sure how the AssetManager batches up OpenGL operations).